# Do you need brackets in a double for-loop in java if only making a single statement inside?

Tags: java, for-loop

I don't know if the second for-loop would be considered a statement to mean that the curly braces are needed.

So what I am asking is would these `for-loops`:

```
for (int i=1;i<a.length;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++){
        a[i][j] = b[i][j]-c[i][j];
    }
}
```

mean the same thing as these `for-loops`:

```
for (int i=1;i<a.length;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
        a[i][j] = b[i][j]-c[i][j];
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: out of curiosity, since Java doesn't enforce indentation restrictions, why would you not include the braces? I find the braces incredibly helpful in java for seeing where loops/functions/whatever begin and end.

Comment: In this case they are not required but it's a good habit to have them.

Comment: @Colleen Ita a good habit to use braces. However its not restricted to java only. Its acceptable in c and CPP also. Like a legacy comeing from them.

Comment: @Colleen just think indentation looks better on a single statement but if it's many statements I can see the need for braces.

Comment: @SJuan76 Because sometimes java subtley allows you to do stuff that is not quite 'correct' and I want to make sure that I know why it works when it works.

Comment: @smit, I specified Java because I'm working in Python most of the time, where indentation is king. I disagree that it looks better but that's personal preference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:** No

**Long answer:** You don't have to but you should. It increases code readability, it can save you from useless debugging and late night hours. Also, [Oracle's code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#449) clearly states that you should always use braces.

You can write this too:

```
for (int i=1;i<a.length;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
        if (a[i][j] > 500)
            if (checkForSomethingStupid(a[i][j]))
                a[i][j] = b[i][j]-c[i][j];
```

Comment: Oh, that is interesting. I didn't realise it was only the first if that started and finished a statement.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need it, but a lot of people believe that the curly brackets improve readability, particularly if the indentation might be inaccurate.    For instance:

```
for (int i=1;i<a.length;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
a[i][j] = b[i][j]-c[i][j];
```

If you were reading that quickly you might not realize that the 3rd line is performed multiple times.  But in this case ...

```
for (int i=1;i<a.length;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++) {
a[i][j] = b[i][j]-c[i][j];
    }
}
```

... it is much more obvious.  And trust me, people have wasted DAYS looking for bugs like that!

And here's another example:

```
for (int i=1;i<a.length;i++) 
    for (int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
        a[i][j] = b[i][j]-c[i][j];
        count++;
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need the braces, because it is one statement. but it is strongly suggested, otherwise one time you will make an coding error. (when adding one statement)

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are the same.

Because the curly braces are necessary to include more than one further statement, but you use only one for after the first (that use an other statement but it is included in the for cycle).

However the use of the braces is very usefull because they simplify the reading, so the better way to write your code would be:

```
for (int i=1;i<a.length;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = b[i][j]-c[i][j];
    }
}
```

Even if, as said in this circumstance they are not necessary..

But, in the following situation:

```
for (int i=1;i<a.length;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = b[i][j]-c[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[i][j]*a[i][j]; //or anything other statement you want to do in this for-cycle
    }
```

the first for-cycle does not need braces because it only includes one statement, the secondo for-cycle needs braces because it includes two statements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both loop are the same. But as per coding convention, it is advisable to use the curly even though you only have a single line of code in your loop blocks. This is to maintain the readability of your code.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned, it is not necessary but it is generally considered good practice.

However, there is a case where it might be necessary.  If you are working on a project where an automated tool enforces code quality restrictions on you (such as checkstyle or PMD), then leaving out the braces will probably fail the build.